# Magento invoice PDF Customization given measures in mm

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

I am trying to customize the invoice PDF in magento. I have requirement such example ..

```
       **Leave space from top 12mm and from sides 10mm.**
```

How can I convert 12mm in magento PDF co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

> Zend PDF uses the same geometry as PostScript. It starts from
>   bottom-left corner of page and by default is measured in **points** (1/72
>   of an inch).([source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html))

1 point = 0.3527777777778 mm.

You can use this [online tool](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/EN/units-converter/typography) to convert **point** to **mm**.
Based on this adjust your code in order to calculate the **points** in **mm**